# Python change reference

Tags: python

Will appending to a list in python a dictionary that already exists in the list change the item or appended at the end?

For example,

I have this in the same run of a loop (this script fills my db with movies)

```
movie = {'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': 0} 
movies.append(movie)
```

Then I update my movie entry with a value for release_date, like so; (with the same run of the loop)

```
movie = {'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': '2018-08-30'} 
movies.append(movie)
```

Will it update the past entry or append a new one at the end there?

Comment: It will add a new dictionary to the end of the list (testing the code in IDLE shows this).

Comment: read and understand this: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It will.

Might I suggest checking the list for the current movie and then if said movie is found, removing it from the list and then appending the new dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The code will add a new dictionary to the end of `movies`:

*From IDLE*

```
>>> movies = []
>>> movie = {'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': 0}
>>> movies.append(movie)
>>> print(movies)
[{'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': 0}]
>>> movie = {'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': '2018-08-30'}
>>> movies.append(movie)
>>> print(movies)
[{'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': 0}, {'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight', 'release_date': '2018-08-30'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Appends at end. Python 2.7.12

```
>>> movie = {'id':102,'name':'The Dark Knight','release_date':0}
>>> movies = []
>>> movies.append(movie)
>>> print(movies)
[{'release_date': 0, 'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight'}]
>>> movie = {'id':102,'name':'The Dark Knight','release_date':'2018-08-30'}
>>> movies.append(movie)
>>> print(movies)
[{'release_date': 0, 'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight'}, {'release_date': '2018-08-30', 'id': 102, 'name': 'The Dark Knight'}]
```